# Event listener for trace as3

Tags: actionscript-3, event-listener, trace

Back again with another question. So I have been trying to research how to create an event listener for trace and I cant seem to be able to find much about it if any at all. I want to be able to send the output of a trace when called into a textfield. I would write my own function for this but the project I am working on is going to be hopefully used by other people with little programming knowledge and pretty much just use trace. Then there would be the correct targeting of my function from a loaded movieclip and I imagine that it would all turn into quite a mess. So if anyone has any ideas or any help regarding this, that would be awesome!

Comment: You are free to grab my debugging panel. There's an answer on another thread that explains how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573773/4687633 After you set it up, you just call **Log.log("Your output here");** from anywhere, so it goes to panel (you can toggle its visibility by predefined keys) and duplicates the output to standard trace output.

Comment: It seems this outputs the panel for all uncaught error events? I have no error events that are not handled. I set up any error to be caught and tell the user what the error was via trace. Since the people I am trying to design this for are not as code savvy as I am. Most just use animate to make art. From glancing over the code and your comment on the other stack post, it really seems like it just targets errors and not trace. Forgive me if I am reading this wrong and as always thank you for your replies and help.

Comment: Uncaught errors is an addition. The main purpose of this class is to provide a simple and easy to use debug panel you can output to from anywhere.